# Liste pages throws error 419, page expired

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have just updated to v6.0 and I got an issue with all pages showing a 419 error. List pages don't work at all anymore and create pages work fine event with the error displayed first.

Laravel debugbar says it's a CSRF mismatch and I get errors in the console saying some assets are not found.

[Screenshot of listed errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8M2l.png)

#### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec  6 2022 15:31:23) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.2.0RC1, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans

#### LARAVEL VERSION:

10.15.0.0

#### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:

backpack/basset: 1.0.0
backpack/crud: 6.0.5
backpack/generators: v4.0.0
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.0.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.1.3

I tried following the upgrade guide several times while making sure I'm not skipping any steps but cannot get to get it to work.

I get there's an issue with storage link as the links in the console are showing double / on the url.
But this was working fine before the update and I've never got this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and it blocked me for days.
All you have to do is change the "APP_URL" variable in the .env file of the Laravel project.

Mine used to be "APP_URL=localhost", but that didn't work.
Then I changed it to "APP_URL=http:// movie.test" and it worked.
knowing that "http:// movie.test" is the local domain name I created for my project.

So all you have to do is change the "APP_URL" variable to the correct address. :-)

Comment: For laravel 10 project inside vagrant vm I had to use port forwarding, the port selected was 8010 thus on the APP_URL variable was the next structure:
APP_URL=http://localhost:8010

External port: 8010.
Internal Port: 8000

And it worked.

Comment: @ecasdevelop Ahhh thank you, I should have figured that out. I noticed that the links Backback was generating were only "localhost" instead of "localhost:xxxx" with the port I'm using. Adding the port to the APP_URL fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open discussion here about it - you can try some of the solutions there - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/discussions/576

1. Try to manually log out by accessing the `/admin/logout` url)
2. Try deleting all cache using `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running locally, run

```
php artisan serve
```

You have to specify the HTTP port, which by default is `:8000` in the `APP_URL` of the `.env` file.